# Clicking ISO does nothing in the 'Make Startup Disk'. Cannot make a USB Boot Drive that I need for work

Tags: boot, usb, iso

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Im using ubuntu for the first time. I tried to install Windows 7 onto my new pc using a usb boot i made on my vista 32bit laptop, but it wasnt detecting any hard drives to install on. [It would give me this message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPIfN.jpg) I made a ubuntu boot drive instead with the same usb, but I know nothing about Ubuntu.

Whenever I select the Win 7 ISO from the file browser in Make Start Up Disk nothing happens at all.

I want to try making a new iso boot on a new usb stick using a different program. My laptop has since died. Ive been trying for hours, but my dyslexia is getting the better of me. Please write to me simply, thank you!

Comment: Where did you get the Windows 7 ISO file from?

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand your question: Do you want to create a Win7 bootable USB from your running Ubuntu installation or do you want to create an Ubuntu bootable USB from your running Vista installation? Do you have the correct ISO file, since your Laptop is a 32-bit-architecture?

Comment: I downloaded the ISO from here http://softwaregeeks.co.uk/downloads/
Same place I bought my key. I tried to get the ISO from Microsoft, but they said my key wasnt accepted because it isnt a retail version, or something along those lines.

I tried making one from my vista but couldnt get it to work, so I now want to create one from within Ubuntu. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: Thanks a lot JonasCz, I did not know that! :)

Answer (score 1):

The "Startup Disk creator" application which comes with Ubuntu *only* supports Ubuntu / Linux ISOs, so it will *not* be able to write a Windows 7 ISO to a USB stick.

In order to create a bootable USB stick for a Windows, on an Ubuntu machine, see [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu?lq=1), or you could burn the Windows 7 ISO to a DVD.